Udev Rule Troubleshooting help
Please help me troubleshoot this. I think it is all correct and yet the rule is not taking. The first rule is supposed to link the device (a teensy arduino clone) to the name /dev/linobase:
KERNEL=="ttyACM?", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="16C0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0483", ATTRS{serial}=="15412350", MODE="0666" SYMLINK+="linobase"
KERNEL=="ttyUSB?", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", ATTRS{serial}=="0001", MODE="0666" SYMLINK+="linolidar"

Note only one Link even though there should be a second link called linobase.
$ python -m serial.tools.list_ports -v -s
/dev/linolidar
    desc: n/a
    hwid: LINK=/dev/ttyUSB0 LINK=/dev/ttyUSB0
/dev/ttyACM0
    desc: USB Serial
    hwid: USB VID:PID=16C0:0483 SER=15412350 LOCATION=1-1.3:1.0
/dev/ttyAMA0
    desc: ttyAMA0
    hwid: fe201000.serial
/dev/ttyUSB0
    desc: CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller - CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
    hwid: USB VID:PID=10C4:EA60 SER=0001 LOCATION=1-1.4
4 ports found

From udevadm monitor --property
UDEV  [205.657779] bind     /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3 (usb)
ACTION=bind
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3
SUBSYSTEM=usb
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/005
DEVTYPE=usb_device
DRIVER=usb
PRODUCT=16c0/483/279
TYPE=239/2/1
BUSNUM=001
DEVNUM=005
SEQNUM=4048
USEC_INITIALIZED=205620177
ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE=1
ID_MM_PORT_IGNORE=1
MTP_NO_PROBE=1
ID_VENDOR=Teensyduino
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Teensyduino
ID_VENDOR_ID=16c0
ID_MODEL=USB_Serial
ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Serial
ID_MODEL_ID=0483
ID_REVISION=0279
ID_SERIAL=Teensyduino_USB_Serial_15412350
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=15412350
ID_BUS=usb
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:020201:0a0000:ff6ac7:
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Van Ooijen Technische Informatica
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=Teensyduino Serial
ID_PATH=platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.3
ID_PATH_TAG=platform-fd500000_pcie-pci-0000_01_00_0-usb-0_1_3
MAJOR=189
MINOR=4

